# AUTOSAR OS configuration example

Tags: configuration, operating-system, embedded, autosar

As with version 3.0, AUTOSAR switched from OSEK-OIL to a XML based format in order to configure their OS. I'm looking now for an example of how this configuration can look like. The AUTOSAR specification unfortunately just covers the configuration parameters. Has anyone an idea where to get an example?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the textual language for Ecuc value configuation provided by Artop, a textual configuration could look like this:

```
module Os = {
    container OsAppMode = {

    }
    container OsOS: ExampleOS = {
        param OsUseParameterAccess = true
        param OsStackMonitoring = true
        param OsStatus = .EXTENDED
        param OsUseGetServiceId = true
        param OsUseResScheduler = true
        container OsHooks = {
            param OsErrorHook = true
            param OsPostTaskHook = true
            param OsPreTaskHook = true
            param OsShutdownHook = true
            param OsStartupHook = true
        }
    }

    container OsEvent : ev1 = {



    }

    container OsTask : task1 = {
        ref OsTaskEventRef = os/Os/ev1
    }
}
```

The generated .arxml would then be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AUTOSAR xmlns="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0 autosar_4-2-2.xsd">
  <ADMIN-DATA>
    <USED-LANGUAGES>
      <L-10 L="EN" xml:space="preserve">English</L-10>
    </USED-LANGUAGES>
  </ADMIN-DATA>
  <AR-PACKAGES>
    <AR-PACKAGE>
      <SHORT-NAME>os</SHORT-NAME>
      <ELEMENTS>
        <ECUC-VALUE-COLLECTION>
          <SHORT-NAME>os</SHORT-NAME>
          <ECUC-VALUES>
            <ECUC-MODULE-CONFIGURATION-VALUES-REF-CONDITIONAL>
              <ECUC-MODULE-CONFIGURATION-VALUES-REF DEST="ECUC-MODULE-CONFIGURATION-VALUES">/os/Os</ECUC-MODULE-CONFIGURATION-VALUES-REF>
            </ECUC-MODULE-CONFIGURATION-VALUES-REF-CONDITIONAL>
          </ECUC-VALUES>
        </ECUC-VALUE-COLLECTION>
        <ECUC-MODULE-CONFIGURATION-VALUES>
          <SHORT-NAME>Os</SHORT-NAME>
          <ADMIN-DATA>
            <SDGS>
              <SDG GID="source">
                <SD GID="VALUE">/osconfig/os.ecucvalues</SD>
              </SDG>
            </SDGS>
          </ADMIN-DATA>
          <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-MODULE-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Os</DEFINITION-REF>
          <IMPLEMENTATION-CONFIG-VARIANT>VARIANT-PRE-COMPILE</IMPLEMENTATION-CONFIG-VARIANT>
          <CONTAINERS>
            <ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>
              <SHORT-NAME>OsAppMode</SHORT-NAME>
              <ADMIN-DATA>
                <SDGS>
                  <SDG GID="source">
                    <SD GID="VALUE">/osconfig/os.ecucvalues</SD>
                  </SDG>
                </SDGS>
              </ADMIN-DATA>
              <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-PARAM-CONF-CONTAINER-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Os/OsAppMode</DEFINITION-REF>
            </ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>
            <ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>
              <SHORT-NAME>ExampleOS</SHORT-NAME>
              <ADMIN-DATA>
                <SDGS>
                  <SDG GID="source">
                    <SD GID="VALUE">/osconfig/os.ecucvalues</SD>
                  </SDG>
                </SDGS>
              </ADMIN-DATA>
              <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-PARAM-CONF-CONTAINER-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Os/OsOS</DEFINITION-REF>
              <PARAMETER-VALUES>
                <ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
                  <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-BOOLEAN-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Os/OsOS/OsUseParameterAccess</DEFINITION-REF>
                  <ANNOTATIONS>
                    <ANNOTATION>
                      <LABEL>
                        <L-4 L="EN">source</L-4>
                      </LABEL>
                      <ANNOTATION-ORIGIN>Ecuc Values Editor</ANNOTATION-ORIGIN>
                      <ANNOTATION-TEXT>
                        <P SI="egal">
                          <L-1 L="EN">/osconfig/os.ecucvalues</L-1>
                        </P>
                      </ANNOTATION-TEXT>
                    </ANNOTATION>
                  </ANNOTATIONS>
                  <VALUE>1</VALUE>
                </ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
                <ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
                  <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-BOOLEAN-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Os/OsOS/OsStackMonitoring</DEFINITION-REF>
                  <ANNOTATIONS>
                    <ANNOTATION>
                      <LABEL>
                        <L-4 L="EN">source</L-4>
                      </LABEL>
                      <ANNOTATION-ORIGIN>Ecuc Values Editor</ANNOTATION-ORIGIN>
                      <ANNOTATION-TEXT>
                        <P SI="egal">
                          <L-1 L="EN">/osconfig/os.ecucvalues</L-1>
                        </P>
                      </ANNOTATION-TEXT>
                    </ANNOTATION>
                  </ANNOTATIONS>
                  <VALUE>1</VALUE>
                </ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
                <ECUC-TEXTUAL-PARAM-VALUE>
                  <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-ENUMERATION-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Os/OsOS/OsStatus</DEFINITION-REF>
                  <ANNOTATIONS>
                    <ANNOTATION>
                      <LABEL>
                        <L-4 L="EN">source</L-4>
                      </LABEL>
                      <ANNOTATION-ORIGIN>Ecuc Values Editor</ANNOTATION-ORIGIN>
                      <ANNOTATION-TEXT>
                        <P SI="egal">
                          <L-1 L="EN">/osconfig/os.ecucvalues</L-1>
                        </P>
                      </ANNOTATION-TEXT>
                    </ANNOTATION>
                  </ANNOTATIONS>
                  <VALUE>EXTENDED</VALUE>
                </ECUC-TEXTUAL-PARAM-VALUE>
                <ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
                  <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-BOOLEAN-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Os/OsOS/OsUseGetServiceId</DEFINITION-REF>
                  <ANNOTATIONS>
                    <ANNOTATION>
                      <LABEL>
                        <L-4 L="EN">source</L-4>
                      </LABEL>
                      <ANNOTATION-ORIGIN>Ecuc Values Editor</ANNOTATION-ORIGIN>
                      <ANNOTATION-TEXT>
                        <P SI="egal">
                          <L-1 L="EN">/osconfig/os.ecucvalues</L-1>
                        </P>
                      </ANNOTATION-TEXT>
                    </ANNOTATION>
                  </ANNOTATIONS>
                  <VALUE>1</VALUE>
                </ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
                <ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
                  <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-BOOLEAN-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Os/OsOS/OsUseResScheduler</DEFINITION-REF>
                  <ANNOTATIONS>
                    <ANNOTATION>
                      <LABEL>
                        <L-4 L="EN">source</L-4>
                      </LABEL>
                      <ANNOTATION-ORIGIN>Ecuc Values Editor</ANNOTATION-ORIGIN>
                      <ANNOTATION-TEXT>
                        <P SI="egal">
                          <L-1 L="EN">/osconfig/os.ecucvalues</L-1>
                        </P>
                      </ANNOTATION-TEXT>
                    </ANNOTATION>
                  </ANNOTATIONS>
                  <VALUE>1</VALUE>
                </ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
              </PARAMETER-VALUES>
              <SUB-CONTAINERS>
                <ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>
                  <SHORT-NAME>OsHooks</SHORT-NAME>
                  <ADMIN-DATA>
                    <SDGS>
                      <SDG GID="source">
                        <SD GID="VALUE">/osconfig/os.ecucvalues</SD>
                      </SDG>
                    </SDGS>
                  </ADMIN-DATA>
                  <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-PARAM-CONF-CONTAINER-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Os/OsOS/OsHooks</DEFINITION-REF>
                  <PARAMETER-VALUES>
                    <ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
                      <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-BOOLEAN-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Os/OsOS/OsHooks/OsErrorHook</DEFINITION-REF>
                      <ANNOTATIONS>
                        <ANNOTATION>
                          <LABEL>
                            <L-4 L="EN">source</L-4>
                          </LABEL>
                          <ANNOTATION-ORIGIN>Ecuc Values Editor</ANNOTATION-ORIGIN>
                          <ANNOTATION-TEXT>
                            <P SI="egal">
                              <L-1 L="EN">/osconfig/os.ecucvalues</L-1>
                            </P>
                          </ANNOTATION-TEXT>
                        </ANNOTATION>
                      </ANNOTATIONS>
                      <VALUE>1</VALUE>
                    </ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
                    <ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
                      <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-BOOLEAN-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Os/OsOS/OsHooks/OsPostTaskHook</DEFINITION-REF>
                      <ANNOTATIONS>
                        <ANNOTATION>
                          <LABEL>
                            <L-4 L="EN">source</L-4>
                          </LABEL>
                          <ANNOTATION-ORIGIN>Ecuc Values Editor</ANNOTATION-ORIGIN>
                          <ANNOTATION-TEXT>
                            <P SI="egal">
                              <L-1 L="EN">/osconfig/os.ecucvalues</L-1>
                            </P>
                          </ANNOTATION-TEXT>
                        </ANNOTATION>
                      </ANNOTATIONS>
                      <VALUE>1</VALUE>
                    </ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
                    <ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
                      <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-BOOLEAN-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Os/OsOS/OsHooks/OsPreTaskHook</DEFINITION-REF>
                      <ANNOTATIONS>
                        <ANNOTATION>
                          <LABEL>
                            <L-4 L="EN">source</L-4>
                          </LABEL>
                          <ANNOTATION-ORIGIN>Ecuc Values Editor</ANNOTATION-ORIGIN>
                          <ANNOTATION-TEXT>
                            <P SI="egal">
                              <L-1 L="EN">/osconfig/os.ecucvalues</L-1>
                            </P>
                          </ANNOTATION-TEXT>
                        </ANNOTATION>
                      </ANNOTATIONS>
                      <VALUE>1</VALUE>
                    </ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
                    <ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
                      <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-BOOLEAN-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Os/OsOS/OsHooks/OsShutdownHook</DEFINITION-REF>
                      <ANNOTATIONS>
                        <ANNOTATION>
                          <LABEL>
                            <L-4 L="EN">source</L-4>
                          </LABEL>
                          <ANNOTATION-ORIGIN>Ecuc Values Editor</ANNOTATION-ORIGIN>
                          <ANNOTATION-TEXT>
                            <P SI="egal">
                              <L-1 L="EN">/osconfig/os.ecucvalues</L-1>
                            </P>
                          </ANNOTATION-TEXT>
                        </ANNOTATION>
                      </ANNOTATIONS>
                      <VALUE>1</VALUE>
                    </ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
                    <ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
                      <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-BOOLEAN-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Os/OsOS/OsHooks/OsStartupHook</DEFINITION-REF>
                      <ANNOTATIONS>
                        <ANNOTATION>
                          <LABEL>
                            <L-4 L="EN">source</L-4>
                          </LABEL>
                          <ANNOTATION-ORIGIN>Ecuc Values Editor</ANNOTATION-ORIGIN>
                          <ANNOTATION-TEXT>
                            <P SI="egal">
                              <L-1 L="EN">/osconfig/os.ecucvalues</L-1>
                            </P>
                          </ANNOTATION-TEXT>
                        </ANNOTATION>
                      </ANNOTATIONS>
                      <VALUE>1</VALUE>
                    </ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
                  </PARAMETER-VALUES>
                </ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>
              </SUB-CONTAINERS>
            </ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>
            <ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>
              <SHORT-NAME>ev1</SHORT-NAME>
              <ADMIN-DATA>
                <SDGS>
                  <SDG GID="source">
                    <SD GID="VALUE">/osconfig/os.ecucvalues</SD>
                  </SDG>
                </SDGS>
              </ADMIN-DATA>
              <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-PARAM-CONF-CONTAINER-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Os/OsEvent</DEFINITION-REF>
            </ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>
            <ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>
              <SHORT-NAME>task1</SHORT-NAME>
              <ADMIN-DATA>
                <SDGS>
                  <SDG GID="source">
                    <SD GID="VALUE">/osconfig/os.ecucvalues</SD>
                  </SDG>
                </SDGS>
              </ADMIN-DATA>
              <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-PARAM-CONF-CONTAINER-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Os/OsTask</DEFINITION-REF>
              <REFERENCE-VALUES>
                <ECUC-REFERENCE-VALUE>
                  <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-REFERENCE-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Os/OsTask/OsTaskEventRef</DEFINITION-REF>
                  <ANNOTATIONS>
                    <ANNOTATION>
                      <LABEL>
                        <L-4 L="EN">source</L-4>
                      </LABEL>
                      <ANNOTATION-ORIGIN>Ecuc Values Editor</ANNOTATION-ORIGIN>
                      <ANNOTATION-TEXT>
                        <P SI="egal">
                          <L-1 L="EN">/osconfig/os.ecucvalues</L-1>
                        </P>
                      </ANNOTATION-TEXT>
                    </ANNOTATION>
                  </ANNOTATIONS>
                  <VALUE-REF DEST="ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE">/os/Os/ev1</VALUE-REF>
                </ECUC-REFERENCE-VALUE>
              </REFERENCE-VALUES>
            </ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>
          </CONTAINERS>
        </ECUC-MODULE-CONFIGURATION-VALUES>
      </ELEMENTS>
    </AR-PACKAGE>
  </AR-PACKAGES>
</AUTOSAR>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the XML, then using SWS, Chapter Test configuration, in this the container of all parameters are mapped and from multiplicity to datatype of particular parameters are already mentioned.

Autosar Modules Descrption file (for each sofware module) can be developed using ARTOP topology.

e.g. Vector or EB provides BSW Module Description files for each BSW modules. which are usually of extension *.arxml's or *.xdn which which are like blank form ( empty parameter files) which then can be loaded into the bundle form into configurator tool, and values can be modified.
If you know the xml and SWS for OS you can develope Os_Ecuc.arxml with all the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AUTOSAR xmlns="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0 AUTOSAR_4-0-3.xsd">
        <AR-PACKAGES>
            <AR-PACKAGE UUID="8bada0df-b371-42bf-8efb-70a5e37848d9">
                <SHORT-NAME>AUTOSAR</SHORT-NAME>
                <AR-PACKAGES>
                    <AR-PACKAGE UUID="255535ce-4bbd-431b-b824-967fa1ba7fd9">
                        <SHORT-NAME>ABC</SHORT-NAME>
                        <ELEMENTS>
                        <IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE UUID="e5f2e035-9407-4b4c-bce8-44831376e6f2">
                            <SHORT-NAME>Arr_2D</SHORT-NAME>
                <CATEGORY>ARRAY</CATEGORY>
                            <SUB-ELEMENTS>
                                <IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE-ELEMENT UUID="f5bca0ab-22f2-49ab-95ea-907ae6b508e2">
                                    <SHORT-NAME>Arr1</SHORT-NAME>
                                    <ARRAY-SIZE>5</ARRAY-SIZE>
                                    <SUB-ELEMENTS>
                                        <IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE-ELEMENT UUID="25d8239a-86fb-4cba-bf8a-6d052a814af2">
                                            <SHORT-NAME>Arr2</SHORT-NAME>
                                            <ARRAY-SIZE>2</ARRAY-SIZE>
                                            <ARRAY-SIZE-SEMANTICS>FIXED-SIZE</ARRAY-SIZE-SEMANTICS>
                                            <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS>
                                                <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-VARIANTS>
                                                    <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-CONDITIONAL>
                                                        <BASE-TYPE-REF DEST="SW-BASE-TYPE">/AUTOSAR/KPIT/Arr2D_Base</BASE-TYPE-REF>
                                                    </SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-CONDITIONAL>
                                                </SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-VARIANTS>
                                            </SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS>
                                        </IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE-ELEMENT>
                                    </SUB-ELEMENTS>
                                </IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE-ELEMENT>
                            </SUB-ELEMENTS>
                        </IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE>
              <IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE S="" UUID="41923e04-c4e4-42b0-b6de-850298a8c757">
                <SHORT-NAME>SingleArray</SHORT-NAME>
                <CATEGORY>ARRAY</CATEGORY>
                <SUB-ELEMENTS>
                  <IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE-ELEMENT UUID="61fd326e-4453-45e8-bd4c-2ad3b4c70e65">
                    <SHORT-NAME>Uint8</SHORT-NAME>
                    <ARRAY-SIZE>4</ARRAY-SIZE>
                    <ARRAY-SIZE-SEMANTICS>FIXED-SIZE</ARRAY-SIZE-SEMANTICS>
                    <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS S="SwDataDefProps_0">
                      <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-VARIANTS>
                        <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-CONDITIONAL>
                          <BASE-TYPE-REF DEST="SW-BASE-TYPE">/AUTOSAR/KPIT/uint8</BASE-TYPE-REF>
                          <SW-CALIBRATION-ACCESS>READ-ONLY</SW-CALIBRATION-ACCESS>
                          <SW-IMPL-POLICY>CONST</SW-IMPL-POLICY>
                          <SW-IS-VIRTUAL>false</SW-IS-VIRTUAL>
                        </SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-CONDITIONAL>
                      </SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-VARIANTS>
                    </SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS>
                  </IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE-ELEMENT>
                </SUB-ELEMENTS>
                <TYPE-EMITTER></TYPE-EMITTER>
              </IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE>

                            <IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE UUID="3dd66464-e1cf-4a8e-917c-0ec540377810">
                                <SHORT-NAME>StructImpl1</SHORT-NAME>
                                <SUB-ELEMENTS>
                                    <IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE-ELEMENT UUID="c29d3da1-f8a8-44ef-b885-3f2dce8258f1">
                                        <SHORT-NAME>ImplData_U8_Arr</SHORT-NAME>
                                        <ARRAY-SIZE>4</ARRAY-SIZE>
                                        <ARRAY-SIZE-SEMANTICS>FIXED-SIZE</ARRAY-SIZE-SEMANTICS>
                                        <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS>
                                            <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-VARIANTS>
                                                <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-CONDITIONAL>
                                                    <BASE-TYPE-REF DEST="SW-BASE-TYPE">/AUTOSAR/KPIT/uint8</BASE-TYPE-REF>
                                                    <SW-CALIBRATION-ACCESS>READ-WRITE</SW-CALIBRATION-ACCESS></SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-CONDITIONAL>
                                            </SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-VARIANTS></SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS>
                                    </IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE-ELEMENT>
                                    <IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE-ELEMENT UUID="1f82a8d3-79c8-48e5-a32f-a35dc8bb8b15">
                                        <SHORT-NAME>ImplData_U16</SHORT-NAME>
                                        <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS>
                                            <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-VARIANTS>
                                                <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-CONDITIONAL>
                                                    <BASE-TYPE-REF DEST="SW-BASE-TYPE">/AUTOSAR/KPIT/uint16</BASE-TYPE-REF></SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-CONDITIONAL>
                                            </SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-VARIANTS></SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS>
                                    </IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE-ELEMENT>
                                    <IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE-ELEMENT UUID="c85c16c7-bbaa-45b2-b604-6412c60869d6">
                                        <SHORT-NAME>ImplData_U32</SHORT-NAME>
                                        <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS>
                                            <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-VARIANTS>
                                                <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-CONDITIONAL>
                                                    <BASE-TYPE-REF DEST="SW-BASE-TYPE">/AUTOSAR/KPIT/uint32</BASE-TYPE-REF></SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-CONDITIONAL>
                                            </SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-VARIANTS></SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS>
                                    </IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE-ELEMENT>
                                </SUB-ELEMENTS>
                            </IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE>
                            <IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE UUID="bde1cfff-5dca-46bf-8365-62037c7e0be7">
                                <SHORT-NAME>UInt8</SHORT-NAME>
                                <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS>
                                    <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-VARIANTS>
                                        <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-CONDITIONAL>
                                            <BASE-TYPE-REF DEST="SW-BASE-TYPE">/AUTOSAR/KPIT/uint8</BASE-TYPE-REF></SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-CONDITIONAL>
                                    </SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-VARIANTS></SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS>
                            </IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE>
                            <IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE UUID="229441c6-c8d7-4857-8a4e-8e4528a1792e">
                                <SHORT-NAME>UInt16</SHORT-NAME>
                                <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS>
                                    <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-VARIANTS>
                                        <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-CONDITIONAL>
                                            <BASE-TYPE-REF DEST="SW-BASE-TYPE">/AUTOSAR/KPIT/uint16</BASE-TYPE-REF></SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-CONDITIONAL>
                                    </SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-VARIANTS></SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS>
                            </IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE>
                            <IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE UUID="8afe59ce-5507-4e5d-a342-2f815ff7cc24">
                                <SHORT-NAME>UInt32</SHORT-NAME>
                                <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS>
                                    <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-VARIANTS>
                                        <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-CONDITIONAL>
                                            <BASE-TYPE-REF DEST="SW-BASE-TYPE">/AUTOSAR/KPIT/uint32</BASE-TYPE-REF></SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-CONDITIONAL>
                                    </SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS-VARIANTS></SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS>
                            </IMPLEMENTATION-DATA-TYPE>
                            <SW-BASE-TYPE UUID="e1e75893-8d85-4b9d-b8c7-6637f52a1833">
                                <SHORT-NAME>uint16</SHORT-NAME>
                                <BASE-TYPE-SIZE>16</BASE-TYPE-SIZE>
                                <BYTE-ORDER>MOST-SIGNIFICANT-BYTE-FIRST</BYTE-ORDER>
                                <NATIVE-DECLARATION>unsigned int</NATIVE-DECLARATION>
                            </SW-BASE-TYPE>
                            <SW-BASE-TYPE UUID="d45625cc-2aab-491b-ba2a-9d1618c518ab">
                                <SHORT-NAME>uint32</SHORT-NAME>
                                <BASE-TYPE-SIZE>32</BASE-TYPE-SIZE>
                                <BYTE-ORDER>MOST-SIGNIFICANT-BYTE-FIRST</BYTE-ORDER>
                                <NATIVE-DECLARATION>unsigned long</NATIVE-DECLARATION>
                            </SW-BASE-TYPE>
                            <SW-BASE-TYPE UUID="1be0e77e-1103-4c29-a8bf-d41a1bbc1a4c">
                                <SHORT-NAME>uint8</SHORT-NAME>
                                <BASE-TYPE-SIZE>8</BASE-TYPE-SIZE>
                                <BYTE-ORDER>MOST-SIGNIFICANT-BYTE-FIRST</BYTE-ORDER>
                                <NATIVE-DECLARATION>unsigned char</NATIVE-DECLARATION>
                            </SW-BASE-TYPE>
                        <SW-BASE-TYPE UUID="fb67bdbb-7d08-4344-b745-cf67b7fc2b1f">
                            <SHORT-NAME>Arr2D_Base</SHORT-NAME>
                                <BASE-TYPE-SIZE>8</BASE-TYPE-SIZE>
                                <BYTE-ORDER>MOST-SIGNIFICANT-BYTE-FIRST</BYTE-ORDER>
                                <NATIVE-DECLARATION>unsigned char</NATIVE-DECLARATION>
                        </SW-BASE-TYPE>
                        </ELEMENTS>
                    </AR-PACKAGE>
                </AR-PACKAGES>
            </AR-PACKAGE>
        </AR-PACKAGES>
</AUTOSAR>
```